# Complex function in terms of z

Tags: complex-analysis

let

$$f(x, y) = x^3 - 3xy^2 + i(3x^2y - y^3)$$

---

How to express $f(x, y)$ in terms of $z$ ?

given that

$$z = a + ib$$
$$a = x^3 - 3xy^2$$
$$b = 3x^2y -y^3$$

I need to find $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ and the textbook says $f(z) = z^3, f'(z) = 3z^2$

If I go backwards

$$z^3 = (x,y)(x,y)(x,y) = (x^2 - y^2, 2xy)(x, y)$$
  $$= (x^3 - 3xy^2, -y^3 + 3x^2y)$$

I can see it, but what if I don't know the answer previously?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice trick you can use. Consider the function $g(z) = f(z,0) = z^3$, with $z$ restricted to the real axis. This function agrees with $f(z)$ on the real line and because they are both holomorphic, the identity theorem tells you that $f(z) = g(z) = z^3$.

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)=f(x,0)=x^3?$

Comment: Thank you, I addressed your comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that the function is differentiable along the real axis( Cauchy-Riemann conditions, by setting $y=0$). If that condition is met, then we simply set $z=\left ( x,0 \right )$, which leads us to $$f\left ( z \right )=z^{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can try to play with the polar representation:
For $x=r\cos\theta,\space y=r\sin\theta$
$$f(x,y) = r^3\cos^3\theta-3r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta+i(3r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta - r^3\sin^3\theta)$$
$$= r^3(\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta + i(3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta - \sin^3\theta))$$
Which are exactly the triple-angle identities
$$=r^3(\cos3\theta + i\sin3\theta)$$
So for $z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$ we have $f(z) = z^3$